# Activate the intent StatusBarNotification

Tags: android

I got an app that reads the status bar notifications, I have a view that shows them, and when click happen I want the relevant intent to be sent to the relevant app.

I tried 
notification.contentIntent.send();

but no success, I get a intent canceled exception.

How can i launch the proper intent?

Comment: post exception logcat.

Comment: post some code or more details